# Neo4j Failed to mark transaction as rollback only

Tags: java, servlets, neo4j

I have a servlet that makes a relations between nodes , it does so in a loop , it may create 
1-999 or more relations in a loop . It does so by loading the data from the array list into 
Neo4j . First time when I run it it works well. Second time if i run in 5 seconds again it gives a  `java.lang.NullPointerException`  . After about a minute it works well again . 
This is the servlet code

```
public class InputDebtDataToNeo4j extends HttpServlet {

static GraphDatabaseService graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("C:\\Users\\Jovo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DebtSolutions\\build\\web\\NEO4J databases\\db1"); 
//Neo4jSinletonDbStart nn=new Neo4jSinletonDbStart();
//GraphDatabaseService graphDB =nn.getInstance();
    private ArrayList<InputData> l111;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        HttpSession session=request.getSession(true); 

        l111= (ArrayList<InputData>) session.getAttribute("hasdata");
        long mynodenumber;
        mynodenumber = Long.parseLong(session.getAttribute("node_id").toString());
        Transaction tx = graphDB.beginTx();
        try {
            Node firstNode;
            Node secondNode;    
            for (InputData element : l111)
            {
                Relationship relationship = null;
                firstNode=graphDB.getNodeById(mynodenumber);
                secondNode=graphDB.getNodeById(element.getNodeidnumber());

                relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode, RelTypes.OWES );
                relationship.setProperty( "amount", "'"+element.getDebtamount()+"'" );  

                out.println( relationship.getStartNode().toString());
                out.println( relationship.getProperty( "amount" ) );
                out.println( relationship.getEndNode().toString() );
           }

           tx.success();   
            //response.sendRedirect("DebtSolutions.jsp");
        } 
        catch(Exception e )
        {
             tx.failure();
             out.println(e.toString());
        }
        finally { 
            tx.finish();
            graphDB.shutdown();     
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

What I get is

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Failed to mark transaction as rollback only
```

What I notices is that it always works ok when I make a change in Netbeans for example hit 
enter for an empty newline and save , the servlet reloads - then is starts the Neo4j other ways it gives exception .

Comment: you commented out the lines where you get the graphDB instance, was that intentional?

Comment: Yes it was I think I can get the same effect with using static - not making it too complicated . What happens is that when I run the code firs time it does ok , second time it fails , if I wait for a 2 mins run it again it works ok again . If I do some change in code-Netbeans , enter space for example do a save , Tomcat reloads servlet it also runs . When it fails I get java.lang.NullPointerException and org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Failed to mark transaction as rollback only

Comment: And I use jdk7 for java

Comment: What I noticed is that it works fine if I comment //graphDB.shutdown();   !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it comes to is that I needed to make a singleton class for creating and shuting down database like this

```
public class GraphDbStarter {
    private static GraphDatabaseService graphdb=null;

    protected GraphDbStarter()
    {}

 //   static GraphDatabaseService graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("C:\\Users\\Jovo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DebtSolutions\\build\\web\\NEO4J databases\\db1"); 
   public static GraphDatabaseService getInstance()
   {
       if(graphdb == null) {
        graphdb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("C:\\Users\\Jovo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DebtSolutions\\build\\web\\NEO4J databases\\db1");
         registerShutdownHook(graphdb);  
       }

   return graphdb;
   }

   private static void registerShutdownHook(final GraphDatabaseService graphdb )
   {
   Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
   {    

       @Override
    public void run()
    {
    graphdb.shutdown();
    }
   });
   }
}
```

and in my servlet use

```
static GraphDatabaseService graphDB=GraphDbStarter.getInstance();
```

without

```
 graphdb.shutdown();
```

in the servlet .Now it works fine...

Comment: If you have something to add please do so.

Comment: Again sometime when I do some changes and my code fails I have to restart the Tomcat to make it work ok.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite like messing up the singleton pattern. Your code is pretty simple now, but it might become more complex. I tend to solve it with a private constructor :

```
public class Database(){
    private static Database instance;    
    private GraphDatabaseService service;

    private Database(){
        Register shutdown hook, create indices, read configuration such as Db Path, ...
        service = whatever service you need.
    }

    public static Database getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new Database();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public GraphDatabaseService getService(){
        return service;
    }
```

Also, don't do all of that in your Servlet/Controller. Create a service layer for your business logic, and a data access layer for persistence. I tend to hide both service and repository implementation behind an interface, but if you are never going to change your implementation, it's not actually necessary.

You've created a very simple application, yet it already looks very cluttered. Keep your code clean in the small applications, and it'll become a habbit for larger applications.